# "Смолит Карфагеном"

Tags: семантика

В одной песне услышал такую строчку:

> Не понимая, что внутри строки наболело,
>
> Не понимая, что внутри **смолит Карфагеном**

Образная сторона мне более-менее ясна: во внутреннем мире рассказчика такие же пустота и отчаяние, как и в этом финикийском городе после визита заклятых друзей из Рима. Однако я не могу уловить буквальное значение словосочетания. Имеется в виду запах дыма от спалённого города? Но слово "смолить", судя по толковым словарям, не значит "пахнуть", "вонять" и т.п. В связи с этим два вопроса:

1. Что же буквально значит словосочетание?
2. Если всё же подразумевается дым спалённой ж̶н̶и̶в̶ы финикийской столицы, то встречали ли вы сами такое употребление слова "смолить", то есть в значении "пахнуть (смолой, гарью и т.п.)"? Допустимо ли оно?

Comment: Автора зовут Фёдоров Мирон Янович.Читаю комментарии и недоумеваю.Как он по вашему мог не знать, где находится Оксфорд, если он окончил его на отделении "Древнерусской английской литературы"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, запах здесь ни при чём. Внутри смолит Карфагеном = горит как Карфаген = Карфагеном. Есть у слова смолит такое значение: Смолить - местн. "палить, жечь". Вот и в груди жжёт.

Может быть, если автор интеллектуал, имелась в виду и особая трагичность: всё внутри горит смолой (смолой и поджигали), потому что после 6 ужасных дней боя сдались около 50 000 изнуренных голодом жителей города, прятавшихся в  укрепленной цитадели на вершине холма. Остальные, не желая быть казненными или оказаться в рабстве, закрылись в храме Эшмуна и подожгли его. Римляне сожгли остатки города. Карфаген был разрушен до основания и предан проклятию, на месте города запрещалось селиться кому бы то ни было. Так что смолит = горит смолой, но в то же время на душе темно, черно, трагично.

Answer (score -1):

Исхожу из этого источника.
https://www.rapgeek.ru/artists/oxxxymiron/tracks/8817/pesenka-gremlina#!

1. Искать смысла в тексте жесткого репа - занятие не из благодарных.
2. На уровне подкорки - да, у автора что-то там сильно смолит в строчке. Типа переживания. Ну как Маяковского "единого слова ради". Только у этого - душа горит. Я так понимаю. Если вообще что-то можно понять.
3. Запах - да, ни при чем. Сам пожар. Карфаген римляне сожгли, а это был едва ли не самый большой по тем временам город. Можно представить, какая там копоть пошла. Вот эта-то копоть и "смолит" у автора.

(++++)
Переношу содержательную часть своих комментариев к ответу Людмиле.

А найти текст не пробовали? Такой прям интеллектуал.)))
 rapgeek.ru/artists/oxxxymiron/tracks/8817/pesenka-gremlina#! – IrinaGL
 15 окт в 7:13

> И текст теперь прочитала, и об авторе. Ну что ж , мы по разные стороны
>   культуры, не люблю андеграунд, эпатаж и матерщину, но зачем отказывать
>   в интеллекте?Всё-таки Оксфорд окончил, да ещё историю изучал, видимо,
>   интеллект (а не интеллигентность) имеется, и мозги есть, только ,
>   может, не туда направил. – Людмила 15 окт в 16:37

не думаю, что он даже знает, где этот Оксфорд находится. Впрочем, это не столь важно. Реп - это реп. Там смысла очень мало. – IrinaGL 16 окт в 0:40
(----)
Под всем этим готова подписаться, смысла в тексте очень мало, а весчь этот поток сознания выглядит порожденным человеком с крайне низким интеллектом, куда тут до Оксфорда.

**Пояснение**. Автор сего опуса - некий субъект с ником Oxxxymiron.
И именно он, Oxxxymiron, утверждает, что он учился в Оксфоде. Где именно - и насколько успешно, не уточняется. 
Ни о каких миронах фадевых в тексте не говорится. Даже если это реальное имя автора, то смешивать лирического героя с с автором - все одно не комильфо. 
А мнение о тексте я могу формулировать без разрешения господина Пересвета. Это-то как раз по теме ресурса, в отличие от требований представить какие-то доказательства в отношении авторства и его личной жизни.

Если у Пересвета еще остались какие-то вопросы по существу, он может задать их здесь.